# How to buy tickets for the EN 499 (Lisinski) train online?

Tags: trains, online-resources, bookings, munich, zagreb

There is a [Euronight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EuroNight) 499 train from Munich to Zagreb, departing at 23:50 daily. What is the price for that journey (one-way, cheap seats) and how can I book it online?

Comment: I got on that train once and I did without a seat reservation. You can try buying it from a Deutsche Bahn ticket machine on the day of departure (if you want a seat, not a bed), I am not sure it ever sells out.

Comment: I'm interested in getting an advance booking discount, so it would be nice to get the ticket in advanced.

Comment: This is really useful for me, Thanks a lot!
It works in https://tickets.oebb.at/en/ticket

Comment: You are saying it's possible to buy tickets at that URL? Could you provide some more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ÖBB (Austrian Railways) will sell you a ticket on EN 499 [on their website](https://tickets.oebb.at/en/ticket/offer). As of this writing it costs €39 for a seat (advanced purchase price), including free reservation.

Add €20 for couchette, which includes a "small breakfast". Or, add €35 if you would like a sleeping cabin including the same breakfast and access to "washing facilities".

Comment: Prices do change with availability, so the prices for dates farther out while still outside popular periods should be lower while popular dates and nearer the time of travel will be more expensive.

Comment: @pnuts if bought in advance the price is way lower. Answer updated.

Comment: That was the price for a trip that started the day after I wrote this comment.

Answer (score 5):

Seat61.com has [a lot of info on this train](http://www.seat61.com/Croatia.htm#Option_2_Munich-Zagreb_sleeper_train). Prices start at EUR 29 (advanced fare).

It's apparently very difficult to book it online but it might possible by phone. Depending on where you are, you might try your luck on [raileurope-world.com](http://www.raileurope-world.com/) or [loco2.com](https://loco2.com/).

Comment: Both Loco2 and Raileurope-world.com are extremely overpriced. I will try my luck at the local train station in Czech Republic and post the results here.

Comment: They are more expensive (don't know about overpriced) but you wanted an online solution. Personally, I would certainly try the train station first.

Comment: Bahn.de offers the same price both online and offline (not for this train though). I was hoping for an alternative Croatian/Slovenian/German railroads website.

Comment: @NikitaSokolsky Yes I know but as you probably noticed, it's not available on bahn.de and other national railway operators' websites so if you want an online solution, Loco2 is what's left. (The Croatian railways' website is barely usable and redirects visitors to Bahn.de for international tickets.)

Comment: No one came up with a better answer. It seems you can only get a ticket offline (without overpaying) :(

Comment: This answer is partially out-dated apparently booking via oebb.at is possible, see new info on seat61 and the currently deleted answer below (for who has 10k+ rep).

Comment: The link from the deleted answer: https://tickets.oebb.at/en/ticket

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it is possible to book this online. When I traveled this route I checked every possible railroad booking site in Europe and it was not possible. I ended up purchasing this ticket one hour prior to departure at the international window in the Zagreb train station for the Croatian kuna equivalent of €59 for a bed in a 6-berth sleeper couchette.